# Audio emitted from speaker not rendering

Tags: rendering, export, audio

I am trying to render my video with 3 separate speakers with their respective audios playing. When I render, the audio is not audible. I have mp3 audio codec and stereo channel set on render, but still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: As long as you hear them in the viewport while in camera view, and you enable audio codecs in the file outputs, it should work fine.

Comment: Did you set up an audio codec for the video file output? By default it is disabled, and you will output a silent movie.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem. The solution comes from Richard Antalik,developer.blender org

Enable *Sequencer* in *Output Properties > Post Processing* panel.

In Blender 3.0 the *Output Properties* (tab) is where you define the size of your output, where to output your file to, encoding for video and audio, etc. You will also find in the same tab the *Post Processing* panel with compositing and sequencer check boxes. Put a check on the *Sequencer*.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same answer more than once, if the questions are the same instead vote to close them as duplicates, thanks.